# What does "rush on" mean in this context?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I looked for its meaning and I found this from [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rush+on):

> A large, sudden, and widespread demand for something.

I am not sure this is the right answer for the next context:

> No French sovereign could dare to withdraw without avenging the first check met with by the French army since Waterloo, and thus was the Emperor **rushed on** to fulfil his own destiny.

*Maximilian in Mexico - Woman's Reminiscences of the French Intervention 1862-1867 Sara Yorke Stevenson*

Comment: Your definition links are a completely different idiom = ***a rush*** (or ***a run***) is when there's a sudden high consumer demand for some product, so the distributors might run out of stock. Your example doesn't look too good to me, but it's obviously using ***rushed*** to mean ***hurried*** (the Emperor was dragged / pushed / hurried / "steamrollered" into doing something). The preposition ***on*** is barely relevant to either of these idiomatic usages.

Comment: If that is a quotation, then please format it correctly (a block quote would probably work better than quotation marks) and cite the source.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Done!

Answer (score 0):

The definition that you found is for the noun "rush", which can be used with the preposition "on". However, in your example "rush" is not a noun; the preceding instance of "was" and the "-ed" suffix suggest that it is instead the past participle form of a verb. (You may want to review how to form the [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice).) [Merriam-Webster's definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rush) aren't a perfect match for this meaning, but I'd say that the closest is:

> to push or impel on or forward with speed, impetuosity, or violence

The closest [definition for "on"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) is:

> 2a: forward or at a more advanced point in space or time
> | went *on* home
> | later *on*

I doubt that the emperor was rushed forward literally "at a more advanced point in space or time"; the use of "on" here is somewhat figurative and means something more like "forward toward some goal".

EDIT:

Another possibility for "on" (suggested in a comment below) is:

> b: in continuance or succession
> | rambled *on*
> | and so *on*

Comment: I'd say the meaning is **2 b :** in continuance or succession, *rambled on*

Comment: @gotube I never said that it was a preposition here; I said that the preposition could be used with the noun "rush". I'm in complete agreement that it's an adverb here.

Comment: @gotube Yes, I considered meaning 2b, but I thought that 2a was a little closer to what was likely intended. I don't think that either entry is a great fit, really, but I guess that we can't expect a free online dictionary to be very comprehensive.

Comment: To me, the quote clearly means the emperor continued to rush, which is 2b, especially considering the example given with it: "ramble on", which means to continually ramble.

Comment: @gotube You may be right; some more context might be helpful.

Comment: @gotube I just edited to add that definition.